# Need help building a rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models that Im working with here: User, Deal, and Investment.

User has many deals
User has many investments

Deal belongs to user
Deal has many investments

Investment belong to deal
Investment belong to user

I want to find all investments from a user where the deal.deal_type_id = 3 for that investment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have setup your associations, its pretty simple.

```
  # user.id = 1
  User.find(1).deals.where(:deal_type_id => 3)
```

Comment: isn't that going to find all Users who have a deal with type 3?

Comment: @stephen, It shouldn't, you could check that in the console (rails c). I updated the example, its a bit nicer. There more ways of doing it.

Comment: yeah makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [squeel](http://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem, then it's quite a bit more intuitive.

Assuming you've already retrieved the user you want to find investments for:

```
user.investments.joins{ deals }.where { deal.deal_type_id == 3 }
```

Comment: I tried in the console after installing the squeel gem, and its returning "NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for "":String"

Comment: whoops - it's joins, not join - also `user` here is a user object that you've already retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Stephen said but for Active Record:

```
type = 3
user.investments.joins('deals').where('deals.deal_type_id == ?', type)
```

Comment: the == might not with specific db backends, like MySQL.